# predict external dataset with models from random forest

Tags: python

I used `joblib.dump` in python to save models from 5 fold cross validation modelling using random forest. As a result I have 5 models for each dataset saved as: `MDL_1.pkl, MDL_2.pkl, MDL_3.pkl, MDL_4.pkl, MDL_5.pkl`. Now I want to use these models for prediction of external dataset using `predict_proba` when the final prediction for each line in my external dataset is an average of 5 models. What is the best way to proceed?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not save the result of cross validation. Cross validation **is not** a training method, it is **an evaluation scheme**. You should build **a single model** on your whole dataset and use it to predict.

If, for some reason, you can no longer train your model, you can still use this 5 predictions by averaging them (as random forest itself is a simple averagin ensemble of trees), however going back and retraining should give you **bettter** results.